# How to return just the number value of a user's attribute in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

At my hospital I am trying to write a script to add security when unlocking a user's account.
when running this code,

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
$user = Read-Host -prompt 'User name of Person locked out'
$id = get-aduser $user -properties '*'| select -property employeeNumber
```

$id outputs as `"@{employeeNumber=someNumber}"`

is there any way to set the $id to just output 'someNumber'?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize `-ExpandProperty 'employeeNumber'` on the `Select-Object` cmdlet.

Alternatively:

```
$id = (Get-ADUser $user -Properties '*').employeeNumber
```